# wget causes "BadZipfile: File is not a zip file" for openpyxl

Tags: python-2.7, debian, wget

I'm using `wget` to download Excel file with `xlsx` extension. The thing is that when I want to deal with the file using `openpyxl`, I get the above mentioned error. But when I download the file manually using fire fox, I don't have any problems.

So I checked the difference between the two downloaded files. I found that the manually one's size is much bigger (269.2 kB) compared to the wget one (7.3 kB), though both files show the same content when open by Excel 2013

I don't add any options for the `wget` just use it like `wget <downloadLink>`

**What's wrong with wget and Excel files?**

Answer (score 0):

If the files are different in size then wget isn't getting the right file. Many websites now rely on javascript to handle links which wget can't emulate. I suspect that if you look at the file with less you'll see some HTML source as opposed to the start of a zipfile.

Comment: Thanks for the reply :) Do you suggest using a similar command or a block of commands so that I can download such kind of files? I need to download the file via command line and not via a browser. BTW, both files show the same content when open by Excel 2013

Comment: Well, if someone is restricting downloads in this way then you should really respect this. However, if you really need to get the file programmatically then I suggest using Selenium to drive a real browser.

Comment: Charlie Clar, actually I'm using Selenium `Selenium2Library` to do everything, till the point after I click on the download link. Then it asks for where to save the file. This window is an OS GUI, so Selenium has no control over it. Therefore, the only way for me was to look for something like `wget`. Also, please don't suggest to change the browser setting to download the file directly without asking where to save it. Because location of the file needs to be a variable.